# How to hide ACCEPT command used for user input in SQL Plus while spooling it in a text file? I have tried "set VERIFY off"

Tags: sqlplus, spool

I am new in SQL Plus. I have multiple queries in a SQL file.

Some queries have variables so whenever I use ACCEPT for that, the output file gets spooled including the command and input I entered. 
Something like that:

**SP2-0003: Ill-formed ACCEPT command starting as ,name char prompt 'Enter name:'**

with the old and new statements like:

**Enter value for name: 'john diaz'**

**old   3: (select * from sample where upper(name) = upper(&name)),**

**new   3: (select * from sample where upper(name) = upper('john diaz'))**

How to remove those statements from output file?? Anyone??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL> SET VERIFY OFF

SQL> ACCEPT name CHAR PROMPT 'Enter name::  ' HIDE

Enter name:

SQL> select * from sample where upper(name) = upper(&name);
```

This way, it will not show **OLD**/**NEW** Value, and also you could enter Value in Hidden Way. No display on what you enter.